# Number of canonical expressions

Tags: boolean-algebra

There is a question:

> What is the number of canonical expressions that can be developed over
>   a 3-valued boolean algebra?

I was trying to solve this. Canonical expression is the combination of minterms. In a 3 valued boolean algebra, the number of minterms is 2 to the power of 3 i.e 8.. so there are 8 minterms. But how do i proceed further? is it using permutation ?

Comment: How do you define two canonical expressions as different? So, I've got minterms like $a=1 \wedge b=u$-assumably this doesn't count as different from $(a=1 \wedge b=u) \vee (a=1 \wedge b=u)$. But is it different from $b=u \wedge a=1$, or do you want only the canonical expressions that define different functions on their variables?